# How add keyboard shortcut for "show desktop" in Xubuntu 20.04?

Tags: xubuntu, show-desktop

In Xubuntu 20.04, I can't find a keyboard shortcut for "show desktop". For example, Ctrl+Alt+D does nothing. Of course I can define a new keyboard shortcut. The problem is I don't know what program performs a "show desktop".

Comment: Just for curiosity: have you tried also Super (typically the key with Win logo) + D ?

Comment: @LorenzKeel, Now that you said I tested it. I have reserved Super key for whiskermenu. That was the reason Super + D didn't work. Why isn't there an item for show desktop in keyboard shortcuts list?

Comment: If you go in Settings -> Window Manager -> Keyboard tab and look for "Show Desktop", you should be able to reconfigure it. Do you have it?

Comment: @LorenzKeel, Thank you. It worked. I'm new to Xubuntu. Previously I looked for it in the "Application Shortcut" tab in Keyboard settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution has been tested in **Xubuntu 20.04.1** run as Live USB.

To check and/or change the keyboard shortcuts for "Show Desktop" feature, go to:

*Settings -> Window Manager -> Keyboard tab*

and look for "Show Desktop" item. Pressing the "Edit button" you can configure a new keyboard shortcut.

Below, an image as reference.

[image]